# Get an array through if statement

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array that I want to get using an `if` statement. This is what I have so far:

```
if($expPositive[0] <= 5 ){
    $data = array();
    $data[$i] = $user_id;
    $i++;
}
$data_arr =  $data;
print_r($data_arr);
```

When I run `print_r($data_arr)`, this is the result:

```
Array ( [1] => 105 )
```

Sometimes the index is 0; i.e.:

```
Array ( [0] => 96 )
```

I would like to get this value in an `if` statement.

Can anyone help me figure this thing out? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain your question with pseudo-code?

Comment: hello i have this if statement which my code goes like this
 if($expPositive[0] <= 5 ){
     $data = array();
     $data[$i] = $user_id;
     $i++;
    }
and i print_r it.
$data_arr =  $data;
   print_r($data_arr);

Comment: so in the $data_arr the result is that one in the above code.

Comment: Please, use `edit` to improve your question.

Comment: tell me what is your expected result? and what is input array looks like? your question is absolutely unclear

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($expPositive[0] <= 5 ){
    $data = array();
    $data[$i] = $user_id;
    $i++;
}
$data_arr =  $data;
print_r($data_arr);
$temp_key=array_keys($data_arr);
//Now  $temp_key will contain keys of the array data_arr
//if $data_arr=Array([1]=>105),$temp_key[0] will have the value **1**
//if $data_arr=Array([0]=>96),$temp_key[0] will have the value **0**
//Now you can use if condition like this:
if($data_arr[$temp_key[0]/*some condition*/)
{
     ///your code
}
```